# botocore.exceptions.clienterror an error occurred (keyTooLongError) when calling copyobject operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

Trying to solve following error "KeyTooLongError" boto client

not sure what should be done to remove this error.

Comment: please share code and stack trace and also refer below link and see if Key length is actually crossing the limit- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

Comment: @ManojRana thaks for the response! aws has mentioned they only allows limited key lenght . I have reduced key size i was passing and now it has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this error as well for some reason limiting the key to exactly 1024 characters worked for me

This caused an error:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

key = "<some-huge-key>"

response = s3.get_object(Bucket="<my-bucket>", Key=key)

>>> (KeyTooLongError) when calling the GetObject operation: Your key is too long
```

Solution:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

key = "<some-huge-key>"

# Limit to exactly 1024 characters
key = key[:1024]

response = s3.get_object(Bucket="<my-bucket>", Key=key)
```